# Why external font (@font-face) takes too much time to load in a web page?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using `@font-face` in an external stylesheet but when I open the page on server, only the text takes to much time to render. Why is this happenning?

Code

```
@font-face{
    font-family: koblenz;
    src: url(../font/koblenz.ttf);
}
@font-face {
 font-family: koblenz;
 src: url(../font/koblenz.eot);
}
@font-face {
 font-family: koblenz;
 src: url(../font/koblenz.eot?#iefix);
}
@font-face {
 font-family: koblenz;
 src: url(../font/koblenz.woff);
}

...
font-family: "koblenz", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

One more question:
IE 8+, Chrome and Safari load text with `koblenz` but Firefox does not. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because you are using the `font-face` so many times. Try something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'koblenz';
    src: url('../font/koblenz.eot');
    src: url('../font/koblenz.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/koblenz.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/koblenz.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/koblenz.svg#koblenz') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```